# gstreamer + raspivid framerate control

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspbian, gstreamer-1.0

I'm using following command to stream video from rapsberry pi:

`raspivid -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=<host> port=<port>`

And capturing:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=<port> ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false`

Now I want to reduce streaming video framerate. I found out that `-fps` argument of `raspivid` command doesn't work as I expected (running `raspivid -t 0 -fps 15 -o -` will not change output video framerate). So I decided to change it using `videorate` gstreamer element:

`raspivid -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=15/1 ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=<host> port=<port>`

But the captured video has super high latency and framerate. Same effect when I'm trying to play video on raspberry without streaming:

`raspivid -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=15/1 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

or event without framerate changing:

`raspivid -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! autovideosink`

How can I change video framerate of h264 encoded video using gstreamer on raspbian?

Debian 8

gstreamer 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the framerate of camera output instead. Try this by adding -fps specification in raspivid:

```
raspivid -t 0 -fps 10 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config- 
interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=<host> port=<port>
```

Comment: Yes, I finally find it out. It seems that version of raspivid I used before has bug and -fps parameter didn't make any changes. Updating raspbian solved the issue.